# kivy，Python，実行時、スクリーン上に何も表示されない

Tags: python, kivy

以下のプログラムでは、kivyを用いてデータベースからキーワードをもとにデータを抽出し出力するソフトを目指しています。

問題点は、一番初めに起動されるTop_Screenが表示されないことです。
なぜ、そうなるのか教えていただきたいです。

`build = Builder.load_file("design.kv")` は `UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp932'` が出るので消しました。

以下がソースコードになります。

**mobiDB_ver1.2.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
import threading
from kivy.core.window import Window

class Top_Screen(Screen):
    """Top画面"""

    def press_enter_button(self):
        sm.add_widget(Search_Screen(name='search'))  # 初期処理を動かしたい画面は遷移の直前に追加する
        sm.remove_widget(self)
        sm.current = 'search'                        #遷移

class Search_Screen(Screen):
    """search画面"""

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Search_Screen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.text = ''  # 検索のキーワードを取得
        self.btn_mythread = threading.Thread(target=self.search_to_uniprot_thread)

    def press_search_button(self):
        #ボタンが押されたときスレッドをスタート

        print("begin")
        sm.add_widget(Search_Screen(name='wait'))  # 初期処理を動かしたい画面は遷移の直前に追加する
        sm.current = 'wait'                        #遷移
        self.btn_mythread.start()                  #スレッドスタート


    def search_to_uniprot_thread(self):
            # Uniprotに接続

            from bioservices import UniProt
            service = UniProt()

            # 検索用の値をqueryとして代入

            query = self.ids["text_box"].text

            # データを抽出し出力.
            result = service.search("keyword:" + query)
            print(result)
            print("finish")

            sm.add_widget(Output_Screen(name='output'))  # 初期処理を動かしたい画面は遷移の直前に追加する
            sm.current = 'output'

class Wait_Screen(Screen):
    """データ抽出中のwait画面"""

    def press_cancel_button(self):
        # ボタンが押されたときSearch画面に戻る

        sm.remove_widget(self)
        sm.current = 'search'


class Output_Screen(Screen):
    """output画面"""

    def press_return_button(self):
        # ボタンが押されたときSearch画面に戻る

        temp = sm.get_screen('select')
        sm.remove_widget(temp)
        sm.remove_widget(self)
        sm.current = 'search'

sm = ScreenManager() #スクリーンマネージャ


class MobiDBApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm.add_widget(Top_Screen(name='top'))
        sm.current = 'top'

        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Window.size = (400, 220)
    MobiDBApp().run()
```

**design.kv**

```
<Top_Screen>:
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size

        Button:
            size: 50,50
            size_hint: None,None
            text: 'Search画面へ'
            on_press: root.press_enter_button() #Top_Screenのメソッドが実行される

<Search_Screen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size: root.size

        Label:
            text_size: self.size
            text: 'Searching in MobiDB'

            halign: 'left'
            size_hint_x: 1
            size_hint_y:0.5
            font_size: 24

        Label:
            size_hint_y: 0.1
            text:''

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_x:0.9
            size_hint_y:0.4
            orientation: 'horizontal'

            TextInput:
                id:text_box
                font_size: 22
                focus: True
                on_text_validate: root.btnClicked_text()

        Label:
            size_hint_y: 0.1
            text:''

        FloatLayout:
            Button:
                text: "Search"
                size_hint_x: 0.23
                size_hint_y: 0.3
                pos_hint: {"x":0.75, "y":0}
                font_size: 20

                on_press:
                    root.manager.transition.direction = 'RiseInTransition'
                    root.press_search_button()

<Wait_Screen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size: root.size

        Label:
            size_hint_y: 0.1
            text:''

        Label:
            text_size: self.size
            text: 'Searching Now'

            halign: 'left'
            size_hint_x: 1
            size_hint_y:0.8
            font_size: 24

        Label:
            size_hint_y: 0.1
            text:''

        Button:
            size: 50,50
            size_hint: None,None
            text: "cancel"
            on_press: root.press_cancel_button() #Top_Screenのメソッドが実行される

<Output_Screen>:
        BoxLayout:
        size: root.size

            Button:
                size: 50,50
                size_hint: None,None
                text: 'finish'
                on_press: root.press_return_button() #Top_Screenのメソッドが実行される
```

Comment: 手元の環境だと、 `design.kv` が読み込まれていないように見えます。 > `build = Builder.load_file("design.kv")はUnicodeDecodeError: 'cp932'がでるので消しました。` これが原因ではありませんか？

Answer (score 0):

自動でkvファイルを読み込ませるにはファイル名はmobidb.kvにしないとですよね。。。